# Solving four coupled differential equation usig NDsolve and getting some error

Tags: differential-equations

Solving four coupled differential equation and one of them Dirac delta function and getting this type of error At t == 9.769456184893095`, step size is effectively zero; \ singularity or stiff system suspected. Could any one help to resolve this issue.

```
    g1 = 1; g = 1; K1 = 0.5; \[Omega]1 = .5; \[Alpha] = \[Pi]/3;
    sol1x = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == 
    g1*Sqrt[10 x1[t]]
    Sin[x2[t]] (-0.5*Abs[x4[t]]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]] + 
     0.5*Conjugate[x3[t]]*x4[t]*Sin[\[Alpha]] + 
     0.5*Abs[x3[t]]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]] + 
     0.5*Conjugate[x4[t]]*x3[t]*Sin[\[Alpha]]) - 
     K1 Sin[x2[t]]*Sum [DiracDelta [(t/T) - i], {i, 1, 20}],
                           
    x2'[t] == (-g1/Sqrt[
     0.4*x1[t]]) (-0.5*Abs[x4[t]]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]] + 
     0.5*Conjugate[x3[t]]*x4[t]*Sin[\[Alpha]] + 
     0.5*Abs[x3[t]]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]] + 
     0.5*Conjugate[x4[t]]*x3[t]*Sin[\[Alpha]]) + x1[t],
                            
    x3'[t] == ((-I*(x3[
         t] (0.5 \[Omega]1 + 
          0.5 g Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]]*Cos[\[Alpha]]) + 
       0.5 x4[t] g Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]]*Sin[\[Alpha]]))/
   Sqrt[(Abs[x3[t]]^2 + Abs[x4[t]]^2)]),
                           
   x4'[t] == ((-I*(x4[
         t] (-0.5 \[Omega]1 - 
          0.5 g Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]]*Cos[\[Alpha]]) + 
       0.5 x3[t] g Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]]*Sin[\[Alpha]]))/
   Sqrt[(Abs[x3[t]]^2 + Abs[x4[t]]^2)]),
                     x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == \[Pi]/2, x3[0] == 0, 
  x4[0] == 1}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, {t, 0, 50}, MaxSteps -> 50000, 
  Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
  Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 4];
```

Comment: You need to define the constant `T`;  you haven't done so in the code you've included.  For example, when I set `T = 1`, your code runs fine.

Comment: Nine times out of ten, the error you've described above is because Mathematica's solution has diverged.  Sometimes this is a real feature of the solutions;  for example, `NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1/(1 - t)^2, x[0] == 1}, x[t], {t, 0, 2}]` throws the same error because the solution is $x(t) = 1/(1-t)$, which diverges at $t = 1$.  So it may just be that your solution really does diverge at some value of $t$.

Comment: It looks like system unstable at `K1>0.4728251`. Last stable solution at `K1>0.4728251, T=2`

Comment: Sorry T=2 Pi is there.

Answer (score 1):

We extend time interval up to `41 Pi` to cover all 20 impulse in `Sum[DiracDelta[(t - i T)/T], {i, 1, 20}]` for `T=2 Pi`.   It looks like this system is unstable at `K1>0.0662` for `T=2 Pi` and `{t,0,41 Pi}`. Last stable solution at `K1=0.06614, T=2 Pi` computed with this code with option `Method -> "ExplicitEuler"`,

```
g1 = 1; g = 1; K1 = .06614; \[Omega]1 = .5; \[Alpha] = \[Pi]/
  3; T = 2 Pi;
sol1x = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == 
     g1*Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Sin[
        x2[t]] (-0.5*Abs[x4[t]]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]] + 
         0.5*Conjugate[x3[t]]*x4[t]*Sin[\[Alpha]] + 
         0.5*Abs[x3[t]]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]] + 
         0.5*Conjugate[x4[t]]*x3[t]*Sin[\[Alpha]]) - 
      K1 Sin[x2[t]]*Sum[DiracDelta[(t - i T)/T], {i, 1, 20}] , 
    x2'[t] == (-g1/
         Sqrt[0.4*x1[t]]) (-0.5*Abs[x4[t]]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]] + 
         0.5*Conjugate[x3[t]]*x4[t]*Sin[\[Alpha]] + 
         0.5*Abs[x3[t]]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]] + 
         0.5*Conjugate[x4[t]]*x3[t]*Sin[\[Alpha]]) + x1[t], 
    x3'[t] == ((-I*(x3[
             t] (0.5 \[Omega]1 + 
              0.5 g Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]]*Cos[\[Alpha]]) + 
           0.5 x4[t] g Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]]*Sin[\[Alpha]]))/
       Sqrt[(Abs[x3[t]]^2 + Abs[x4[t]]^2)]), 
    x4'[t] == ((-I*(x4[
             t] (-0.5 \[Omega]1 - 
              0.5 g Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]]*Cos[\[Alpha]]) + 
           0.5 x3[t] g Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]]*Sin[\[Alpha]]))/
       Sqrt[(Abs[x3[t]]^2 + Abs[x4[t]]^2)]), x1[0] == 1, 
    x2[0] == \[Pi]/2, x3[0] == 0, x4[0] == 1}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, {t, 
    0, 41 Pi}, Method -> "ExplicitEuler", StartingStepSize -> 0.0002, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
```

Visualization of stable and unstable numerical solution

```
LogPlot[Evaluate[Abs[{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t]}] /. sol1x[[1]]], {t,
   0.1, 41 Pi}, PlotLegends -> {x1, x2, x3, x4}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"K1 = ", K1}], AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Note, that with  explicit Euler we can compute up to message `General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.` at `t=115`. We can increase or decrease `StartingStepSize` and rationalize to get more precise solution. For the basic case with `K1=0.5` we can pass error at `t == 9.769456184893095` and visualize what happened with solution after that. Figure 2 shows numerical solution computed with step size 0.001 (left) and 0.0002 (right)
[image: Figure 2]

From the last Figure and from the message we suppose, that there is some discontinuity due to `DiracDelta`. To remove this discontinuity, we integrate first equation around `t= i T`, and finally we have

```
 T = 2 Pi; Integrate[ 
 Sin[x2[t]]*Sum[DiracDelta[(t - i T)/T], {i, 1, 20}], {t, 0, 41 Pi}]

Out[]= 2 \[Pi] (Sin[x2[2 \[Pi]]] + Sin[x2[4 \[Pi]]] + 
   Sin[x2[6 \[Pi]]] + Sin[x2[8 \[Pi]]] + Sin[x2[10 \[Pi]]] + 
   Sin[x2[12 \[Pi]]] + Sin[x2[14 \[Pi]]] + Sin[x2[16 \[Pi]]] + 
   Sin[x2[18 \[Pi]]] + Sin[x2[20 \[Pi]]] + Sin[x2[22 \[Pi]]] + 
   Sin[x2[24 \[Pi]]] + Sin[x2[26 \[Pi]]] + Sin[x2[28 \[Pi]]] + 
   Sin[x2[30 \[Pi]]] + Sin[x2[32 \[Pi]]] + Sin[x2[34 \[Pi]]] + 
   Sin[x2[36 \[Pi]]] + Sin[x2[38 \[Pi]]] + Sin[x2[40 \[Pi]]])
```

Therefore we can use `WhenEvent` instead of `Sum` as follows

```
g1 = 1; g = 1; K1 = 1/2; \[Omega]1 = 1/2; \[Alpha] = \[Pi]/3; T = 
 2 Pi; eps = 10^-9;
sol1x = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == 
    g1*Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Sin[
      x2[t]] (-1/2*Abs[x4[t]]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]] + 
       1/2*Conjugate[x3[t]]*x4[t]*Sin[\[Alpha]] + 
       1/2*Abs[x3[t]]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]] + 
       1/2*Conjugate[x4[t]]*x3[t]*Sin[\[Alpha]]) , 
   Sqrt[2/5*x1[t]] x2'[
      t] == (-g1) (-1/2*Abs[x4[t]]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]] + 
        1/2*Conjugate[x3[t]]*x4[t]*Sin[\[Alpha]] + 
        1/2*Abs[x3[t]]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]] + 
        1/2*Conjugate[x4[t]]*x3[t]*Sin[\[Alpha]]) + x1[t], 
   Sqrt[(Abs[x3[t]]^2 + Abs[x4[t]]^2)] x3'[
      t] == ((-I*(x3[
           t] (1/2 \[Omega]1 + 
            1/2 g Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]]*Cos[\[Alpha]]) + 
         1/2 x4[t] g Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]]*Sin[\[Alpha]]))), 
   Sqrt[(Abs[x3[t]]^2 + Abs[x4[t]]^2)] x4'[
      t] == ((-I*(x4[
           t] (-1/2 \[Omega]1 - 
            1/2 g Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]]*Cos[\[Alpha]]) + 
         1/2 x3[t] g Sqrt[10 x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]]*Sin[\[Alpha]]))), 
   x1[eps] == 1, x2[eps] == \[Pi]/2, x3[eps] == 0, x4[eps] == 1, 
   WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 Pi] == 0, 
    x1[t] -> x1[t] - K1 2 Pi Sin[x2[t]]] }, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, {t, eps,
    50}, Method -> "ExplicitEuler", StartingStepSize -> 0.0002, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 5]
```

Note, that this code runs up to `t=54.9`.
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: How to resolve the unstable problem.

Comment: @user68207 Do you suppose that time should be `t>40 Pi`? In a case of unstable problem what do you expected to get?